# Returning a vector of Eigen::Map<const Matrix..>

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a function that is taking an input class and doing some calculations with it. This class then returns multiple `Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Matrix3Xd>`, and I need to return those out of the function. I'm hoping to avoid copying the matrices here since they're rather large. But C++ doesn't allow a vector of const maps. I'm wondering if there's a decent way to do this.

Here is what my current code structure looks like:

```
std::vector<Eigen::Matrix3Xd::ConstMapType> foo(std::shared_ptr<T> input)
{
     // Do some calculations with the input here
     ....

     // Return the updated matrices
     std::vector<Eigen::Matrix3Xd::ConstMapType> matrices;
     for( int i = 0; i < input->numberMatrices(); i++ )
     {
          matrices.push_back(input->getMatrix(i));
     }
     return matrices;
}
```

where the function `getMatrix()` returns a `Eigen::Matrix3Xd::ConstMapType`.

Is there any way to return these matrices without making a copy here?

I tried changing the return type to `Eigen::MatrixXd::MapType` in order to sidestep the const-ness. But since the function `getMatrix()` returns a const map, this wasn't allowed, and I can't find a way to remove the const either.

I also tried just copying the matrices, which works, but it is very costly and not feasible to do here.

Answer (score 1):

Using -- one may say abusing -- maps like that is not a good idea. Their assignment operator copies to the mapped matrix while containers expect them to copy the map itself. This may very well lead to significant issues down the line such as when invoking copy-assignment from one vector to another. Thankfully placement-new works so at least initialization is okay.

That warning out of the way, this compiles:

```cpp
std::vector<Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Matrix3Xd>> foo(std::shared_ptr<T> input)
{
     // Return the updated matrices
     std::vector<Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Matrix3Xd>> matrices;
     for( int i = 0; i < input->numberMatrices(); i++ )
     {
          matrices.emplace_back(input->getMatrix(i));
     }
     return matrices;
}
```